# Contravariant or covariant tensor in electromagnetism?

Tags: electromagnetism, tensor-calculus, maxwell-equations, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, covariance

I have a question about the following 2 tensors: the permittivity tensor and Maxwell's stress tensor. I was wondering if someone can explain which one is contravariant or covariant, and show why that is true?

I understand contravariant vs. covariant vectors, but am having having trouble extending this to rank-2 tensors.

Comment: *There are two common tensors used in electromagnetism: the permittivity tensor and Maxwell's stress tensor.* The electromagnetic field tensor is at least as important as these.